# Returning a list of the nonzero entries of a matrix in Maxima

Tags: function, matrix, moodle, maxima

The question is as simple as the title implies, alhtough I'm limited by the fact that I'm trying to build a Moodle STACK question and can't therefore access all of Maxima's libraries (nor put expressions on multiple lines in the `question variables` form-field, among other limitations that I'm  probably not even aware of yet). The basic matrix operations like retrieving a row of a matrix seem to be available, though.

Is there a ready-made function for this purpose ([**the documentation**](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_23.html) implies there isn't), or do I need to make one of my own? Because of the mentioned limitations, doing it myself might not be possible.

Comment: There isn't a built-in function to return nonzero elements of a matrix, although there is `sublist` and `sublist_indices` which filter (i.e. select elements according to a predicate) of a list. What do you expect the output of the nonzero-matrix-elements to look like? It seems it might be straightforward to invent such a function given the list filtering functions.

Comment: I&#39;m working on a Simplex-algorithm question, and it would be really handy if I could pick the nonzero entries out of the first row of the solution matrix. The `maximize_lp`-function is loaded, but its use has been restricted by the system admin, so I can&#39;t use that to come up with the teacher answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, assuming the problem is "pick the nonzero entries out of the first row of the solution matrix." Try this:

```
sublist (M[1], lambda ([x], notequal (x, 0)));
```

assuming `M` is the matrix in question.